# Choose between two SQL statements using CASE or something else

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a dropdown and I want to check the selected value first before I run my SQL command so here is my logic: if the selected value of the dropdown is not `'ALL'` then I want to run this sql statement:

```
select distinct Location 
from myTable 
where PROGRAM = '"+program+'"
```

else if selected value of the dropdown is set to `'ALL'` then I want to run this SQL command instead:

```
select distinct Location 
from myTable
```

Here is my my code which works fine but not the way I want it to work. How can I modify the SQL command so I can check the condition that I mentioned above? Thanks

```
protected void BindServiceList(DropDownList ddlService)
{
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)GV_MJJ.HeaderRow.FindControl("ddlProgram");

        string program = ddl.SelectedValue;
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct LOCATION" +
                        " from myTable where PROGRAM = '" + program + "' ");
        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();

        ddlService.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddlService.DataTextField = "LOCATION";
        ddlService.DataValueField = "LOCATION";

        ddlService.DataBind();

        con.Close();

        ddlService.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["Filter_Serv"].ToString())
                .Selected = true; 
}
```

Comment: It's not okay to put data into a query like this: `where PROGRAM = '"+program+'"`. That leaves you vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: i know i will change that later.  thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you just use an `IF` statement to determine what string the `cmd` sqlcommand variable should be set to?

Comment: Why wait? Build it right in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change your SQL command instead create different SQL command's text based on the condition. Also you should use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead of string concatenation. Your code is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Consider enclosing your connection and command object in [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) as that will ensure resource disposal at the end of block.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        if (program.Equals("All", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select distinct LOCATION from myTable";
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select distinct LOCATION from myTable WHERE PROGRAM = @program";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@program", program);
        }
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        ddlService.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddlService.DataTextField = "LOCATION";
        ddlService.DataValueField = "LOCATION";
        ddlService.DataBind();
        con.Close(); // can be left out because of `using` statement
        ddlService.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["Filter_Serv"].ToString())
                .Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: AddWithValue() is evil :(

Comment: I think you meant it is evil when type in C# is different from type in DB :) But from OP's code it appears that he is comparing strings, so it should be fine here :)

Comment: Not necessarily. Even strings can cause big performance problems if the sql column is a varchar instead of an nvarchar.

Comment: I didn't know about that. Thanks, I guess in that case OP can use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@program", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = program;`,

Comment: Also, `AddWithValue` generates cache pollution (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx). `Add` without size could potentially generate the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
protected void BindServiceList(DropDownList ddlService)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)GV_MJJ.HeaderRow.FindControl("ddlProgram");
    string program = ddl.SelectedValue;
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString;
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString) )
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct LOCATION from myTable where PROGRAM LIKE @Program", con) )
    {
         //guessing at column type/length here
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@Program", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = program;

        con.Open();
        ddlService.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddlService.DataTextField = "LOCATION";
        ddlService.DataValueField = "LOCATION";
        ddlService.DataBind();
    }
    ddlService.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["Filter_Serv"].ToString())
            .Selected = true; 
}
```

Notice that I fixed your sql injection vulnerability! Also notice that I changed the `=` to a `LIKE`. Then you can set the `value` property for the `All` item  in the `ddlProgram` control to: `%`. (See the [`AppendDataBoundItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property if you need help getting that working with a databound ddl). Using that wildcard with the `LIKE` operator will result in the query returning all locations.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `Parameterize` your query.

Since there are already solutions using `c#`. I will propose a `SQL` solution.

You could do a `Case` in your `WHERE` CLause by passing a parameter that suggests if the dropdown value is `ALL`. 
Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Location
FROM myTable
WHERE (
        CASE 
            WHEN @IsAllSelected = 0
                THEN PROGRAM
            WHEN @IsAllSelected = 1
                THEN 1
            END
        ) = (
        CASE 
            WHEN @IsAllSelected = 0
                THEN @Your_program_value
            WHEN @IsAllSelected = 1
                THEN 1
            END
        )
```